# property On Error type for images on subreport doesn't works?

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, subreport

There is some trouble with the property "On Error type" for the images on subreports?
 This works fine when the image it's placed on the principal report, i send it a String null or "" and puts blank or icon. But doesn't works when I place the image on subreports, throws `JRException: Image read failed`

```
ArrayList dataHeaderNoSubreport = new ArrayList();
dataHeaderNoSubreport.add(new ppalReport(""));    //has an attribute called imageUrl, this works if i don´t send parameters in fill report

ArrayList dataHeader = new ArrayList();
dataHeader.add(new Header(""));                  //subreport, param image url

Map parameters = new HashpMap();
parameters.put("subreportHeader",  new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataHeader));  
...
JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataReport = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataHeaderNoSubreport);
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("principal.jasper");   //contains a field called imageUrl and the subreport
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, dataReport);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you think mischeivous?

Comment: hi Octopus, i add a part of my test code. I notice that when i add the subreport content on the principal report. The reports that have images on the principal don´t have troubles, when i send a valid url show the image (both, principal and subreport). Maybe need some configuration in ireport

Comment: note: originally i just have the header with image on the subreport, i conserve this for test purposes and because i see that  "on Error type" property works when the subreport content (specifically the image) is on the principal report.